# Need help figuring out what this js line is about

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, dns, cloudflare

I found this code of a DNS-Lookup tool on codepen and edited it for fun. On my localhost everything works just fine but whenever I try to implement it on a website, the tool doesn't work anymore. This is what my current code looks like:

```
<form id="form" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid gray;">
   <label>Hostname:
   <input type='text' maxwidth='80' placeholder="domain-name.tld" autofocus required id="input" style="padding: 3px;"/> 
   </label>  
   <button id="myBtn" style="padding: 3px; text-align: center;">Abfragen</button>
   <br><br>
   <code id="data" style="display: inline-black; text-align: left; white-space: pre;"></code>
</form>
<script>
   const records = ["A", "AAAA", "CAA", "CNAME", "MX", "NS", "TXT", "SRV"];
   
   const dnsFetch = async (type, target) => {
     const res = await fetch(`https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=${target}&type=${type}`, {
       headers: {
         Accept: "application/dns-json",
       },
     });
     if (!res.ok) {
       throw res;
     }
     const i = await res.json();
     return i.Answer ? i.Answer : [];
   }
   
   const dnsRecords = async target => {
     const results = {};
     const promises = [];
     records.forEach(type => {
       const promise = dnsFetch(type, target).then(response => {
         results[type] = response;
       }).catch(err => {
         console.error(err);
         results[type] = [];
       });
       promises.push(promise);
     });
     await Promise.all(promises);
     return results;
   }
   
   document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const target = document.getElementById("input").value;
     dnsRecords(target).then(data => {
       document.getElementById("data").textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
     });
   });
</script>
```

I think that the problem is being caused by the third js line where I locate my fetch source. Since the source is cloudflare-dns.com I think that my server is blocking the third party website. I think that I could just allow cloudflare the access to my website with my .htaccess. But I don't want to do this yet, since I don't exactly understand what this is even doing? Why do I need cloudflare-dns.com as a source to call dns records of a website and can this be solved somehow else? If it helps, here is the full codepen project that I found: https://codepen.io/umarcbs/pen/QWEbWLx

I appreciate any help I can get, thanks :)

Comment: Look in the console and network tab. You will likely see a CORS error

Comment: I'd assume this is about CORS? You could try executing the `fetch` request with the `no-cors` mode.